# error while doing npm install

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am trying to do 'npm install' inside one of my folders but i am getting error code **E403 Forbidden** :

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher 
to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher 
to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail 
on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as 
possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 403 Forbidden: 
https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.3.tgz

npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: binary-extensions@^1.0.0
```

My npm version is 5.5.1
My node version is v8.9.1

Also my system was formatted today and I had to re-install and re-setup everything from scratch. npm install was working till yesterday before my system was formatted.

I have attached the log file here.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/files/1499291/2017-11-23T13_25_27_656Z-debug.log

Thanks in advance

EDIT: every npm install is failing.
for reference here are the entries in my .npmrc file:
    `registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/`
    `proxy=http://user_name:password@proxy:port`
    `https-proxy=http://user_name:password@proxy:port`
    `strict-ssl=false`

I have tried many commands to get this working but no luck.
Note: my password contains '@' symbol but i have encoded it in my .npmrc file as %40

Comment: `sudo npm install` ?

Comment: according to `node-uuid` github, name of npm package has been changed to `uuid` try using `npm install uuid`

Comment: @phanther but that is only a warning that can be ignored, the error is at the last, with error code 403:
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: binary-extensions@^1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i got around this particular problem. Seems like i had to update http to https in registry, and E403 was gone. But still i was facing other issues so decided to downgrade npm to 3.10.10 and node to 6.10.3.

Answer (score 0):

From the first line it's saying old node-uuid module is deprecated and won't be maintained moving forward. Try reinstalling using these commands.

```
npm uninstall --save node-uuid
npm install --save uuid
```

In the second line it's asking for installation of **minimatch**
So try running the command :

```
npm install -g minimatch@3.0.4
```